# Access archived messages through gmail api

Tags: javascript, gmail, gmail-api

I need to access all (and only) archived messages through gmail's api.

The documentation isn't very helpful: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

Something like this query should get the job done:

```
in:anywhere -in:inbox -in:spam -in:trash
```

But that still pulls some emails from inbox. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try just:

```
-in:inbox
```

in:anywhere includes spam/trash where by default they are excluded.

Also, you didn't specify but this query with threads.get() will return threads where 1 or more messages are archived, other messages in the thread may be in inbox still. messages.get() will only return archived messages.